# Bing News feed to PHP

Tags: php, rss, bing

This is my code:

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http://www.bing.com/news/search?q=obama&format=rss');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'image' => $node->getElementsByTagName('News:Image')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 1;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<item>';
    echo '<title>'.$title.'</title>';
    echo '<link>'.$link.'</link>';
    echo '<description>'.$description.'</description>';
    echo '<News:Image>'.$image.'</News:Image>';
    echo '<pubDate>'.$date.'</pubDate>';
    echo '</item>';
    }
```

I can not extract the image url in the tag  ***News:Image***  the rest is OK

The feed output is in this [link](http://megalinks.xyz/feed.php)

Comment: `News:Image` is not a tag. It's `Image` tag within `News` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

In the output section you did not defined the variable `$image` and the tag you need to search for is, as stated by @u_mulder, Image. The following incorporates those changes and appears to output the desired results:-

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http://www.bing.com/news/search?q=obama&format=rss');
$feed = array();
foreach ( $rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node ) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'image' => $node->getElementsByTagName('Image')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}

$limit = count( $feed );
for( $x=0; $x < $limit; $x++ ) {

    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    $image = $feed[$x]['image'];

    echo '<item>';
    echo '<title>'.$title.'</title>';
    echo '<link>'.$link.'</link>';
    echo '<description>'.$description.'</description>';
    echo '<Image>'.$image.'</Image>';
    echo '<pubDate>'.$date.'</pubDate>';
    echo '</item>';
}
```